# TDD/Unit Testing advice on my very simple shopping cart

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd

I've written a very simple shopping cart in javascript and I want to write some automated tests on it.  I've not really done any TDD before so I'm new to writing unit tests.  Can anyone offer any advice on anything I need to do to my code to make it unit testable?  I've got functions that call other functions and I'm not sure if that's going to cause a problem or not.  Any advice on improving my code is welcome too.

```
    total: function(){
       var total=0.00;
       for(var i=0; i<shoppingBasket.length; i++){
            total += shoppingBasket[i].price;  
        }
         $('#total').html('total = '+currency+total.toFixed(2));
         this.totalBogof(total);
    },
```

[This](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZNQfAzfM0EY14CrAbJPI?p=preview) is what I've got so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TDD is about writing the test(s) first and then the production code. So to do this pure TDD, you would need to start again!

Define a list of tests from your requirements, pick an easy one for starters, then go into the TDD Cycle;

- Write a failing Test,
- Write enough code to pass the test
- Refactor

http://beyondcoding.net/articles/TDDOverview.html

Focus on testing behaviour, i.e what you want your code to do rather than how it does it. This will ensure a good design and won't affect methods calling other methods if you stick the the cycle.